# Escape backslash with sed command when the next character is "t"

Tags: bash, sed, escaping, backslash, bcftools

I'm using this sed command to replace the string `"##INFO=<ID="` with `"\t%"` :

```
bcftools view -h /data/ExAC.r1.sites.vep.vcf | grep "^##INFO=<ID=" | sed $'/^##INFO=<ID=/{ s//'\t%INFO' /; s/,.*//; p; }''
```

but what I get is exactly my desired output, but instead of a backslash, it doesn't print anything. If I remove the single quotes around `\t%INFO` in the sed command, it automatically tabs the output, so I don't want that either.

How can I escape the backslash so that it just prints a backslash?

Comment: Did you try `\\t`?

Comment: yes, that didn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sed $'/^##INFO=<ID=/{ s//'\t%INFO' /; s/,.*//; p; }''
```

1.)The dollar sign in front doesn't seem to have a point

```
sed '/^##INFO=<ID=/{ s//'\t%INFO' /; s/,.*//; p; }''
```

2.)You cant just nest single quotes. I dont know how this "works" I wouldnt expect it to.

```
sed '/^##INFO=<ID=/{ s//\t%INFO /; s/,.*//; p; }'
```

3.) This replaces the string with a tab then a %INFO. Then prints it. escape it once.

```
sed '/^##INFO=<ID=/{ s//\\t%INFO /; s/,.*//; p; }'
```

4.) This replaces the stinge with a \t%INFO then prints it, resulting in tab %INFO. Escape it again.

```
sed '/^##INFO=<ID=/{ s//\\\\t%INFO /; s/,.*//; p; }'
```

5.)This should work.

But there is an easier answer using a capture group. It looks like you are looking for this?

```
bcftools view -h /data/ExAC.r1.sites.vep.vcf \
| grep "^##INFO=<ID=" \
| sed -E 's/^##INFO=<ID=([^,]*),.*/\\t%INFO \1/'
```

To get all on on line:

```
bcftools view -h /data/ExAC.r1.sites.vep.vcf \
| grep "^##INFO=<ID=" \
| sed -E 's/^##INFO=<ID=([^,]*),.*/\\t%INFO \1/' \
| awk '{printf "%s ", $0}'
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. Now, the output is multiple lines, but how can I get that all on one line?

Answer (score 1):

Reference [Bash Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quoting.html)

$'string' is called ANSI C quoting interprets backslash sequence, just use single quote quoting to avoid interpret characters the drawback is that it can't contain single quote, but different string qutoed can be concatenated.